# WooCommerce how to change the "return to shop" button text?

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I can change the button link using the `woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect` hook, but i cannot find a "nice" way to change the button text.
I would avoid modifying the core file `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-empty.php` every time woocommerce gets updated.

Any other ideas?
Thanx.

Comment: You can move template file your theme's folder and change it as you desire. `This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-empty.php.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it this way. I have changed 'shop' to 'store' in the following example.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_woocommerce_return_to_shop_text', 20, 3 );

function change_woocommerce_return_to_shop_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case 'Return to shop' :

                $translated_text = __( 'Return to Store', 'woocommerce' );
                break;

        }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Hi this isn't working for  me have they changed something

Comment: Hi @pud, it wasn't working for me until I fixed the case string. I was typing wrong here. Than worked perfectly!